# ExtentReports: HtmlReporter not starting when running an executable jar file created using maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven, selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am trying to execute my test cases programmatically  using TestNG. The virtual suite file is executing fine. But, the Extent Report is not being generated.

Getting the following exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No reporters were started. Atleast 1 reporter must be started to create tests.
        at com.aventstack.extentreports.Report.createTest(Report.java:69)
        at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.createTest(ExtentReports.java:241)
        at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.createTest(ExtentReports.java:254)
        at com.automation.service.impl.ExtentReportService.setParentExtentTest(ExtentReportService.java:56)
        at com.automation.service.impl.ExtentReportService.startTest(ExtentReportService.java:64)
        at com.automation.tests.BaseTest.beforeMethod(BaseTest.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:520)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Right now, I have set my report to generate at the following location:

```
E:/selenium/reports/extent-reports/
```

And I am saving my screenshots in my root folder by the string: `"./"` which basically is storing the screenshots in `E:`.

Another observation:

1. I ran `mvn clean install -DskipTests=true`  from command line.
2. After that I switched to the target folder and ran the following command: `java -jar jar-file-name.jar`
3. Looks like every test cases is failing because of the `IllegalStateException` it is throwing.
4. But the screenshots were being captured in the `target` folder, which technically should be stored in the root fodler.

I tried to change locations of the report and the screenshots. Also let me share the code snipped of my ExtentReportService class:

```
private static void initializeExtentReport(Configuration config) {
        if (extent == null) {
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(getReportName(config));
            ClassLoader classLoader = ExtentReportService.class.getClassLoader();
            File extentConfigFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("extent-config.xml").getFile());
            htmlReporter.loadXMLConfig(extentConfigFile);
            extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
            extent.setSystemInfo("Environment", config.getAutomationServer());
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

This issue got fixed with the other issue I was having.

So, the main problem I was having was loading the `extent-config.xml` file. Thus, I changed the location for loading the `extent-config.xml` file as follows:

```
File extentConfigFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("extent-config.xml").getFile());
```

to

```
File extentConfigFile = new File("./classes/extent-config.xml");
```

In this manner, the test cases will execute smoothly.