# extent-config.xml not able to load in Jenkins while executing automation.jar

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102340/extentreports-htmlreporter-not-starting-when-running-an-executable-jar-file-cre). Please go through the answer that I posted.

The issue is, when I am executing the jar file, the `extent-config.xml` file is not found. The stacktrace is as follows:

```
    com.aventstack.extentreports.configuration.ConfigLoader <init>
    SEVERE: ./classes/extent-config.xml
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./classes/extent-config.xml (No such file or directory) 
at com.aventstack.extentreports.configuration.ConfigLoader.<init>(ConfigLoader.java:49)
at com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.AbstractReporter.loadXMLConfig(AbstractReporter.java:64)
```

So, is there any way that I can load the `extent-config.xml` file using `classLoader.getResource("extent-config.xml").getFile()` or by `File("./classes/extent-config.xml")`?

The `extent-config.xml` is located at `/src/main/resources/`.

Comment: Found one thing. I have to use getResourceStream() instead of getResource() when executing jar.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but elegant solution: Code these configurations in the class as following:

```
htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
```

But still figuring out a way to use getResourceStream().